# easily enable or disable cron

Tags: cron

Whenever I need to enable crons, I will copy the cron file to the spool folder.

```
cp /home/shantanu/shantanu /var/spool/cron/
chown shantanu:root /var/spool/cron/shantanu
```

Will this work?
Any issues I may face?

update: using CentOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official way to disable some cron jobs for specific user is type `crontab -e -u <user>` and put a `#` at the begin to comment out.

---

**UPDATE**

> Because cron file is going to be a part of shell script.

Try this:

```
crontab -l -u shantanuo > shantanuo.cron
sed -i 's/^/#/' shantanuo.cron
crontab shantanuo.cron
rm -f shantanuo.cron
```

Comment: Isn't copy easier than this? This is going to be one time job. I will keep the cron file ready as txt file and copy it to spool just before taking my application in production. I still do not see any risk in doing so.

Answer (score 4):

It *may* work. **But..**

As the previous posters said: Don't do this. Use `crontab -e`. Directly editing the files may work, but isn't robust practice. Your stuff could break any time when updating the involved components. Also, it's not very portable, other systems may store the files in a different place. It's like implementing "printf" by yourself instead of using the standard iolib.

So, don't do it this way.

edit: And if you need to generate the crontab with a shell script, then just pipe your stuff into `crontab` (It even knows the pseudo-file '-' ! Read the man page.).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use command `crontab -e`, or if you are logged in as root, `crontab -e -u shantanu`?

Comment: Because cron file is going to be a part of shell script.

Comment: Err.... what? Please elaborate a bit more. :-)

Comment: He meant the crontab won't be created interactively. I edited my answer below to take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not work depending on which operating system (and which version of cron) you are using. Checking some Linux boxes, their cron man page says this

> Additionally,  cron checks each minute to see if its spool directory's mod‐ time (or the modtime on /etc/crontab) has changed, and if it has, cron will then  examine  the  modtime  on  all  crontabs  and reload those which have changed.  Thus cron need not be restarted whenever a crontab file is  modified.   Note  that  the crontab(1) command updates the modtime of the spool directory whenever it changes a crontab.

So, providing the `/var/spool/cron` directory's mtime is updated then cron will check the individual crontabs to see if they have been updated a reread them.

If though we look at a Solaris 10 box it's cron man page says this

> cron only examines crontab or at command files during it's own process initialization phase and when the crontab or at command is run. This reduces the overhead of checking for new or changed files at regularly scheduled intervals.

So on a Solaris 10 system (and probably others) you would have to use the crontab command to change the files and inform cron that it should reread it's crontab files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suspend jobs without having to restart cron (which may affect jobs run e.g. every 3 minutes) you could use lock files, easily created or removed in a script.

```
*/3 0 * * * [ ! -f /tmp/job.lock ] && /path/to/job
```

So to suspend the job use:

```
touch /tmp/job.lock
```

Restart the scheduling within cron by:

```
rm /tmp/job.lock
```

The beauty of this is that you can use different lock files for different jobs (or groups of jobs if they all use the same lock file) without worrying about interrupting scheduling or breaking cron through mistakes in editing (by script or by hand) the crontab.